# USB USPS Postage Scale API

Tags: c#, usb, hid, usps

I'm trying to integrate a USPS postage scale with a C# application and I'm having no luck.  I actually have 2 scales, one is a Mettler Toledo PS60 and the other is the USPS PS-100 (http://www.measurement-ltd.com/ps-100-det.html).  The MT scale works beautifully with Mike O'Brien's HidLibrary (https://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary).  However, the USPS scale does not (Please note that this is NOT the Stamps.com scale, which DOES appear to work with the HidLibrary).  I know the scale is working because I downloaded the Postage Metering software from USPS and that reads the scale just fine.

I also downloaded a USB analyzer and it shows nothing coming back from the scale when no other applications are talking to it, so that suggests it isn't constantly sending out data and needs to be polled.  I further confirmed this by launching the USPS Postal Meter software and the analyzer started showing data to/from the device.  However, this data doesn't make any sense to me, nor have I had any luck trying to duplicate it in my own application.

As an example, with an exactly 1lb package on the scale, the analyzer shows it receives an 8 byte hex response as follows: 07 54 04 00 FF FF 00 00.  With nothing on the scale, it shows this: 07 00 00 00 FF FF 00 00.  That suggests that the 2nd and 3rd bytes somehow indicate 1 lb, but I have not been able to crack the code.  It also looks like the polling command to get the scale data is 90 DE 80 00 00 00 00 00 (as seen from the analyzer), however this didn't seem to work for me from my application.

So I guess I have 2 issues.  First, I can't get the scale to talk back to me.  The only way is if the metering application is running.  So I need to figure that out.  Second, even when I do get data, it doesn't make any sense.

Does anyone have any experience with this or could point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: I have no experience in this, but on StackOverflow usually it is much better to post a sample code even not working so other people could happen to reproduce or have a better understanding. In your case it might be hard to find someone using exactly the same devices but you never know !

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't much code to share.  I'm really asking about the protocol for this device since the libraries everyone uses for other scales (which works with the Mettler Toledo one) doesn't work with this.  Hopefully someone out there has some experience with this.  I'm happy to share any details that may help, I'm just not sure what that would be.

Comment: Can you put a sample code that does not work and a sample code that works ? I agree with you, you would need alot of luck to find some person who has exactly the same issue and managed to overcome it ? I would try to contact the manufacturer if I was you.

Comment: Hi Brian. If it is a HID device, it should have a HID report descriptor. Does your USB analyzer let you see this information? Also, investigate the USB standard document: USB HID Usage Tables, Point of Scale.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same thing and finally got those scales to work. Here is what I found about the message.

SM WW WW 00 FF 00 00

- S => sign (+ or -). 0 is +, 8 is -
- M => mode. 1: gram, 7: lb oz /, 3 lb oz., 2: oz
- WWWW => Weight in gram (Kg for 75lb scale) and little-endian base 16.

(Please note that only first 3 bytes are used)

With your example:
07 54 04 00 FF FF 00 00

+0454 grams = 1 lb 0/0 oz

---

It is a HID device, to get this interrupt message you need to set a Feature (weight)
90 de 80 00 00 00 00 00

To init the device you need to set this feature
a0 de a0 00 00 00 00 00

Here is the DLL I used
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539684%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

---

**Protocol sequence example**

App to Scale (init mode)
--> a0 de a0 00 00 00 00 00

(wait 1s for scale initialization and tare)

App to Scale (get weight)
--> 90 de 80 00 00 00 00 00

Scale to App (interrupt)
<-- 07 54 04 00 ff ff 00 00

App to Scale (get weight)
--> 90 de 80 00 00 00 00 00

Scale to App (interrupt)
<-- 07 54 04 00 ff ff 00 00

etc