# Reading weight from scale with RS232 to USB cable

Tags: android, serial-port, usb, scale

I am trying to write an Android app that reads weight from scales and shows the result. Here is what I have done until now and some info about situation.

1. My scale has a rs232 output port and I have a rs232 to USB cable and an OTG for connecting to my Android device.
2. I wrote the code for reading data from serial port and printed on my device correctly (I am sure my code is working fine so I haven't posted it here).

Here is my problem:

The scale only sends 'boot' to device every minute, and I couldn't read weight from scale anyway. I guess the problem is that scale doesn't send the weight but I acted like the manual of scale described the way of connecting to PC.

What do you think should I do?

Is it because I used an RS232 to USB converter instead of RS232 to VGA (for connecting to computer)?

As I said my scale sends 'boot' every minute so I can say the connection and reading is right and strong but I can't send weight from scale.

Comment: You mentioned that you wrote code for reading data from the scale and printing it onto the device? What device exactly is that? What is the data it's reading back? Is it hex data? byte data?

Comment: i meant my android device. It is LG G3 but i think doesn't matter :)
its ascii code in hex and i changed it to see the right value.

Comment: Does it always seen the exact same data?

Comment: yeah its always the 'boot' word.
do you think i should send some data to scale to let it know i need weight?
i read that if i send 90 de 80 00 00 00 00 00 to scale, makes scale to return weight on my device.
Here is the link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841458/usb-usps-postage-scale-api?rq=1

Comment: @Ali Ghadiri can you please share the code,which you tried.

Comment: were you able to solve the issue if yes which cable you used for connecting the weight scale. I tried rs232 to usb and otg cable to connect to android app and its doesn't show anything or any connected device.

Answer (score 0):

if have a multimeter with RS232 port. if i want to get a value from the multimeter i have to send a hexadecimal '`D`' and then the multimeter answers with a value. normally it should not matter if you use a RS232 to USB converter because this is a common USB CDC ACM device class that every linux system recognizes and loads the kernel module (`cdc-acm` http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/class/cdc-acm.c) see `lsmod` on the android ...

Comment: but i need to know what should i do to make the scale send weight to me,should i send a character to it or not i dont know but i think scales should send weight automatically or by pressing print button. sadly none of them works for me .

Comment: in most scales is a serial protocol command that requests the weight from the scale see http://www.billproduction.com/Bill_Redirect_scale.pdf page 8 (pdf has a bit strange design...)